# Trying to correct the word pregnart

Tags: java, substring, indexof

I'm trying to correct the word 'pregnart' so it says 'pregnant' instead. Instead of printing a substring that deletes the `r` and inputs the `n`, `n` is instead placed next to the `r` and replaces the first letter in How.

```
package Lesson1;

public class grammarCorrector{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String message = "How hard should I sex to become pregnart?";
        message = message.substring(0,39) + "n" + message.substring(1, message.length());
        int messageSize = message.length();
        System.out.println(messageSize);
        System.out.println(message);
        /*String s ="123123123";
        s= s.substring(0,3) + "foobar" + s.substring(6,s.length());
        System.out.println(s);*/
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting lesson.  What class are you taking?

Comment: nothin', I just saw it on a try not to laugh video

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I’m sorry I didn’t get it. `n` is placed next to `r` as in `pregnarnt`? Or replaces the first letter in `How`as in `now`? Or both? Also, since it seems this should be a question — what was the question? Please ask it explicitly so we know without doubt what to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wish to replace the 39's character, it should be:

```
message = message.substring(0,39) + "n" + message.substring(40);
```

However, I think you missed the count by 1 and it should be:

```
message = message.substring(0,38) + "n" + message.substring(39);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the word that needs to be replaced is "pregnart", maybe you can try the String.replace() method?

Such as:

```
message.replace("pregnart", "pregnant");
```

The above method takes the old String and replace it with the new String